# Replace all subsequent values after the first appearance of a value within a subset Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where I've so far created something similar to the below table:

```
Parent      Child     Overall Risk            Bucket
0  CW12345  CW34565          Low       Low to High
1  CW12345  CW28394         High               N/A
2  CW12345  CW77646     Moderate  Moderate to High
3  CW12345  CW09871         High               N/A
4  CW12345  CW66542          Low   Low to Critical
5  CW12345  CW13356     Critical               N/A
6  CW12345  CW98452          Low   Low to Critical
7  CW12345  CW78899     Critical               N/A
```

The full report has about 1,000 Parents which in turn have x number of Children. The Overall Risk field is tied to the Child. The exercise is to evaluate if the Risk level of Child 2 is greater than Child 1 (and if 3 is greater than 2 and so on). I need the Bucket column to stop after it has identified a "to x" condition, such as Low to High **within the same parent**. Once it has identified Low to High, it should not identify any other "x to High" scenario and instead replace with N/A. Basically each combination of occurrences should only be able to appear once. Below is the kind of output I'm looking for (New Bucket column).

```
Parent    Child       Overall Risk            Bucket       New Bucket
0  CW12345  CW34565          Low       Low to High      Low to High
1  CW12345  CW28394         High               N/A              N/A
2  CW12345  CW77646     Moderate  Moderate to High              N/A
3  CW12345  CW09871         High               N/A              N/A
4  CW12345  CW66542          Low   Low to Critical  Low to Critical
5  CW12345  CW13356     Critical               N/A              N/A
6  CW12345  CW98452          Low   Low to Critical              N/A
7  CW12345  CW78899     Critical               N/A              N/A
```

This question is similar to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72611100/replace-all-subsequent-column-values-after-the-first-instance-of-a-value-greate) but I need the python version. Any help is much appreciated. Ultimately this is being written to excel, so I need the solution to generate a column.

Comment: Please don't include your sample data as an image, it's impossible to copy/paste this for testing. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for some suggestions.

Comment: you are basically looking for the highest value conditioned on the current highest value?

Comment: Please, type `df.head(10).to_dict()` and copy and paste it to the question instead of the image.

Comment: edits made you can now copy and paste, thank you for the feedback. @codeBB yes basically find the first highest value (say anything "to high" is worth 3) and then replace all the other 3s with N/A. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Update: this solution worked for me without creating a new column.

```
cols = ['Bucket]
for i in cols:
    df[i] = df[i].mask(df.duplicates(['Parent'], i]))
```